# Share metabase dashboards with team members

Tags: sql-server, share, metabase

I am new to Metabase. And I have Metabase dashboards that I want to let team members be able to see.

The Metabase is running on a remote server, and I want the team members to access it from there personal PCs. how can I let them access it?

I tried serverIP:3000/???????? but still, it's not working

Comment: you should deploy Metabase on the server like aws elasticbeans. or you can save , share and embed saved links with anyone. please refer https://metabase.com/docs/v0.23.0/administration-guide/13-embedding.html

Answer (score 0):

By default Metabase will listen to `localhost`. you need to change  default  value for `MB_JETTY_HOST environment variable`

```
export MB_JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0
java -jar metabase.jar
```